# Graf($f$) is a recursive set iff $f$ is a recursive function iff Graf($f$) is a recursively enumerable set

Tags: logic, algorithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms

I  only have proved that if graf($f$) is recursive set then is recursively enumerable set by $(n_0, m_0) \in Graf(f) $ 
$$h(n):= \begin{cases} (n, m) \textit{ If } (n,m) \in Graf(f) \\(n_0, m_0) \textit{ If no} \end{cases}$$
which is recursive.

I know that $Graf(f)$ is a recursive set iff the characteristic $$Graf(f)(n,m):= \begin{cases} 1 \textit{  if } (n,m) \in Graf(f) \\0 \textit{ If no} \end{cases}$$ is a recursive function.

**Edit:** 
From the definition if $Graf(f)$ is recursively enumerable then there exists a recursive predicate $R$ such that $$(x, y) \in Gra(f) \Leftrightarrow \exists z R(x, y, z)$$
Thus, $f(x)= (\mu z [R(x, (z)_0, (z)_1])_0$ is recursive, where $()_i$ is the recursive function of Gödel for tuples.

Furthermore, if $f$ is a recursive function then 
$$(x, y) \in Graf(f) \Leftrightarrow f(x)=y$$
is a recursive set because $=$ is a recursive relation.

Comment: What is the context? Specifically, are you given that $f$ is a total function? Without some assumption like that, the statement is not true in general.

Comment: I want to show that all those are equivalents

Comment: You need to provide more information. The statement you are trying to prove is not true under the usual terminology without some additional assumption.

Comment: Okey, to clarify that $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $Graf(f)=\{(n, f(n)) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, Thank for you help!